# Agora live streaming token access for audience

Tags: android, access-token, live-streaming, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

Based on my limited experience, it seems that when a broadcaster starts a live broadcast channel using the token generator, the same token is not available for the audience to use to access the channel.

Question: I would like to know if this actually happens. And if so, do I need to create a new token for every audience that wants to access the channel? If all audience share the same token, will it affect other features or it is okay?

Furthermore, it seems that when joining a channel, you have to use the same uid that is used to create the token, and I would like to verify this too.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put the uid as "0" when a user joins the channel, the Agora background will automatic assign a unique uid for that user. And in this case, you can use the same token to join the channel for different users.

Comment: When I create the token, do I need to put the uid as 0 as well?

Saw this from Agora's documentation:
"When using a token to join a channel, ensure that the App ID, user ID, and channel name that you use to generate the token is the same as the App ID that you use to initialize the Agora service, and the user ID and channel name that you use to join the channel."

Comment: Yes, you need to put uid as 0 in this case.